# ¿Como se puede solucionar error: "No se pudo encontrar el archivo ISAM instalable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   public static void ROC_ExcelToDatagridView (DataGridView dgv)
        {
        path = "";
        try
            {
            try
                {
                 OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog ( );
                 file.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx";
                 file.Title = "Seleccione el Archivo de Excel";

            if (file.ShowDialog ( ) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                if (file.FileName.Equals ( "" ) == false)
                    {
                    path = file.FileName;
                    }
                   }
                    hoja = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox 
            ("Escriba el nombre de la hoja!", "Excel a Datagridview" );
           string conexion = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data 
        [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]Source:" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'";
            oCon = new OleDbConnection ( conexion );
            oCon.Close ( );
            oCon.Open ( );
            oda = new OleDbDataAdapter ( "Select * from [" + hoja + "$] where Fecha is not null and Importado is null", oCon );
            dt = new DataTable ( );
            oda.Fill ( dt );
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            oCon.Close ( );
                }
            catch (OleDbException e)
                {
                MessageBox.Show ( "ERROR: " + hoja + " "+ path +" "+ e.Message);
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)                                                                                                                                                     
            {
            MessageBox.Show ( "Error al momento de cargar los datos del Excel de la hoja " + hoja + " "+ path +" a la tabla del formulario. " + ex.Message + " " + ex.ToString ( ), "ERROR DE CARGA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si te vaya a funcionar:

Para resolver este problema, elimine los nuevos parámetros de la cadena de conexión. Para ello, siga estos pasos:

- Abra el libro de Excel.
- En la cinta de opciones de datos , haga clic en el botón conexiones .
- En el cuadro de diálogo Conexiones del libro , seleccione la conexión a la base de datos de Access y, a continuación, haga clic en Propiedades.
- En el cuadro de diálogo Propiedades de conexión , haga clic en la ficha definición .
- Elimine los siguientes parámetros de la cadena de conexión:

  - Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo validación = False;
  - Almacenamiento en caché de OLEDB:Limited DB de Jet = False;
  - Jet OLEDB:Bypass discriminante validación = False
- En el cuadro de diálogo Propiedades de conexión , haga clic en Aceptar. En este punto, deben actualizarse los datos.
- En el cuadro de diálogo Conexiones del libro , haga clic en Cerrar y, a continuación, guarde el libro actualizado.

https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/3041386/could-not-find-installable-isam-error-when-you-refresh-a-data-table-in